# How to get intelliJ Java project on Google App Engine Flex

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, app-engine-flexible

I've created a Spring MVC project that can be deployed to my GAE instance very nicely.  Now I'm trying to make it so that I can deploy it to the flex environment with IntelliJ with no luck.

My project structure is as follows:

```
\src
   \main
       \appengine
            app.yaml
       \java
            normal java project files
       \resources
            property files
```

When, in IntelliJ, I create a new Run Configuration of "Google App Engine Deployment" the setting / environment is always "App Engine Standard Environment."  I can't seem to make this be part of the flexible environment.

My current app.yaml:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I've tried copying all of the setting I can find from example project on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java)

Here's a screenshot of my deployment 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you also happen to have an `appengine-web.xml` configuration file in your project? If so, this will supersede any flex configuration and the plugin will assume an App Engine standard deployment.

If so, try removing it (or renaming it) and then recreate the deployment run configuration. At this point it should be marked as targeting the App Engine flexible environment.

If you don't have this config file (or if renaming it doesn't help, or if your list of deployment sources does not include any war/jar artifacts), then its possible that you have a native IntelliJ project (not built with Maven / Gradle etc.) and that your Artifact settings are insufficient.

For your target artifact to be deployable to App Engine flexible you need to ensure that you have a non exploded artifact set up (either a war, or a jar if your project has an embedded server):

- Open Module Settings: right click on the root of your project -> Module Settings
- Click on 'Artifacts' on the left
- Check what artifact types you have listed.

  - If its only an exploded war then try creating a new war (non-exploded) artifact - select Web Application archive, then choose your module
  - Save this and then recheck your deployment run configuration

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've done this already, but perhaps you just missed something simple: the flexible environment requires a special IntelliJ plugin, Cloud Tools for IntelliJ ([installation quickstart instructions](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/quickstart-IDEA)).